# matrix transformation for state space matrices

Tags: state-space

Can we use matrix transformation for the A,B,C,D matrices involved in the state space analysis?
e.g.

[image]

In the above figure the state variables are not numbered, like which one is X1 and which one is X2 and the same goes with U. It implies that every time i change the notation of the state variables, i am going to get another set of state equations. 
The picture shows two such cases:
[image]

My doubt is:"can i apply matrix transformation to A,B,C,D matrices individually which should in a way imply that the naming doesn't affect the matrices as they are transformable from one form to another(as long as the state variables are not changed)."

Comment: As long as the matrices define the dynamics, the notation is irrelevant. But it makes sense to use a notation that relates to system structure. What matrix transformation are you applying?

Comment: I am referring to transformations like multiplying a row with some constant and adding it to another row of the matrix. coz the answer that i got was different from the one mentioned in the question until i did row column interchange.